# Unknown command when I use \G with -e

Tags: mysql

I want to remotely run the "show master status" command to get the bin log file and position.

```
mysql --user=<user> --password=<passwd>  -e "show master status\G";
ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\G'.
```

I want to get the result vertically and then use grep or awk to get the bin log file and position.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just ran this same command, works fine for me. What version MySQL are you running?

Comment: ^ I'm with Ethan, works here (mysql 5.5.31, shell bash 4.2.45)

Comment: MySQL 5.5.31. If I login using mysql client on server mysql> show master status\G; works.

Comment: What if you escape your slash like `\\G`?

Comment: Tried that too. Didn't work!